# Phantom pass a php variable to js

Tags: javascript, php, phantomjs

I know there are hundreds of questions about how to pass php variable to JS but i tried a several solution and nothing worked.

I'm pretty new to javascript, i'm using phantomjs to have the URL of an external webpage.

I have this script.js

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onError = function(msg, trace) {
  //prevent js errors from showing in page.content
  return;
};
page.open('http://www.google.com', function () {
    console.log(page.content); //page source
    phantom.exit();
});
```

called by getweb.php

```
<?php
exec ('phantomjs script2.js ', $html);
var_dump($html) ;
?>
```

works perfect.
But If i want to put a php variable in place of google.com it does not work, i guess (just guess...) it's because phantom is no interpreted by navigator.

I tried to put

```
    <script>
var adress = '<?php echo "http://www.google.com" ; ?>'; 
</script>
```

before to execute and change my script with

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onError = function(msg, trace) {
  //prevent js errors from showing in page.content
  return;
};
page.open(adress, function () {
    console.log(page.content); //page source
    phantom.exit();
});
```

but it just take hours without nothing happening.

**What can I do to pass a php variable to script.js ?**

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best thing to do is pass in extra arguments when you execute Phantom.JS with your script.  I can't test in your context, but try something like this.  In your PHP:

```
exec ('phantomjs script2.js "http://example.com/"', $html);
```

Then in your JavaScript, do a `console.log()` on `system.args`.  One of them should be `http://example.com/`.  See also: http://phantomjs.org/api/system/property/args.html